# Rxjs buffer the emitted values for specified time after source emitted values

Tags: rxjs

I have a `source$` observable collecting a stream of data if there are some events trigger. I want to collect these data which occurred in a specified time into array.

```js
const eventSubject = new Subject();
eventSubject.next(data); 

const source$ = eventSubject.asObservable();
source$.pipe(takeUntil(destroyed$)).subscribe(
    data => {
      console.log(data);
    }
);
```

The above `source$` handle emitted data immediately.

Now i want to improve this that wait for a few seconds and collect all data happened in that specified time and emit once. So i modify to use with `bufferTime` like below:

```js
const source$ = eventSubject.asObservable();
source$.pipe(takeUntil(destroyed$), bufferTime(2000)).subscribe(
    data => {
      console.log(data);
    }
);
```

After testing with `bufferTime`, I found that it emits every 2s even source is not receiving data. If source not receiving data, it emit empty object.

What i want is only when `source$` receiving data, then start to buffer for 2s, then emit value. If source$ not receiving data, it shouldn't emit anything.

I checked the `bufferWhen`, `windowWhen`, `windowTime` not all meeting my requirements. They are emitting every time interval specified.

Is there have other operator can do what i want?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go for `connect(shared$ => ...)` and `buffer(signal$)`.

I think something along these lines:

```js
source$.pipe(
  connect(shared$ => shared$.pipe(
    buffer(shared$.pipe(
      debounceTime(2000)
    ))
  ))
)
```

`connect` creates a shared observable so that you can have multiple subscriptions on the source without actually opening those subscriptions to it.

In there I run a `buffer`, whose selector is the `debounceTime` of the same source, so that it debounces for that much (i.e. will emit the array when source$ doesn't emit for more than 2 seconds)

Maybe what you need is `throttleTime(2000, { leading: false, trailing: true })` instead of debounceTime. It depends on your use case.

Comment: I will test later if this match my requirement or not. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a `filter` operator to ignore the empty object emission

```
const source$ = eventSubject.asObservable();
source$.pipe(takeUntil(destroyed$), bufferTime(2000),filter(arr=>arr.length)).subscribe(
    data => {
      console.log(data);
    }
);
```

Comment: There still exist a timer running. Every 2s timer is expensive and wasting resources in my opinion. So I don't want to trigger timer when there is no data starting to receive.

Comment: You can complete stream to complete once it emits an empty object. but in that case the stream is dead and no longer under your watch.

Answer (score 1):

The optimal solution for this case is to use buffer operator with a notifier of debouceTime operator.

For example :

```
const source$ = eventSubject.asObservable();
source$
  .pipe(
  // buffer: accumulate emitions to an array,until closing notifier emits. (closing notifier is the argument below)
    buffer( 
      // debounceTime : will grab the emit that afterwards 2 seconds has passed without another emit.
      $source.pipe(debounceTime(2000))
).subscribe(
   // will return the data that has been emitted througout the 2 seconds in a form of an array , where each item in the array is the emits, by the order they were triggered.
    data => {
      console.log(data); 
    }
);
```

[buffer](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/buffer):

> Buffers the source Observable values until closingNotifier emits.

[debounceTime](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/debounceTime):

> Emits a notification from the source Observable only after a particular time span has passed without another source emission.

This solution in contrast of the filter operator solution, will not keep an interval/timer alive.
And its pretty clean and elegant IMO.